# Regex to find comment in c# source file

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I can't get my regex to match the header of a c# code file.
I basically want need to return the header if it exists.

Example:

```
#define debug
//****************************************************************************************************
//  <copyright file="" company="">
//      Copyright (c) . All rights reserved.
//  </copyright>
//  <project>Engine</project>
//****************************************************************************************************

code here

//some other comment here

more code here

//another comment here
```

My regex looks like this:

```
(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*\+[^*/]))*\\*\+/)|(?://.*)
```

but it only matches this line:
//****************************************************************************************************

and not the rest of the comment.

Comments can also end like this `"*/"`.

whats wrong with my regex? why doesn't it catch the whole block?

Comment: Have you tried using RegexOptions.MultiLine?

Comment: I am using MultiLine, but it only returns 1 line and that's the first. I am coding in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one - and you can pull out the entire comment (with the "//" or the group within to get just the text. This will return a match for each line. Please use the "Multiline" option to run this:

```
^/[/|*](.+)$
```

Comment: Sure, it's unclear if the asker whats the // or /* or */ part of the comment or just the "body."

Comment: This also works, and again I didn't think it would return an array, but just a single block with the whole comment.

Comment: I want the whole comment and not just the body:)

Comment: This does return the whole comment - one line at a time. Instead of grabbing the value from the group, just grab the entire match value.

Answer (score 1):

Need multiline

```
(^\/\/.*?$|\/\*.*?\*\/)
```

Comment: This works, and actually my own example does also. I see that it returns and array with the resut, but I was just expecting a single string with the whole block:x

Comment: Mine is a generic one for matching comments.  If you just want to match your exact format (notice that it really is a bunch of //'s together), you can try: `(^//\*.*?$)+` (multiline).  This will match all lines prefixed with `//*` in a single block.  Sorry I wasn't clear with what you want before.

Comment: Now if you only want a block bracketed by stars (on the first and last line only): `(^//\*+?$(?:^//.*?$)^//\*+$)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd like to extract the pseudo-xml code so the following expression should work. Note that you'll still have to remove the leading "//" in each line.

```
//\*+\n((?://.*\n)+)//\*+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex pattern:  (/*([^*]|[\r\n]|(*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))**+/)|(//.*)

see more https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-find-code-comments-9d1f7a29/